# Excel Create scrollable area

Tags: microsoft-excel, scrolling, scrollbar

Yesterday, I decided that it would be a good idea to keep track of my income and expenses using an Excel spreadsheet, so I created a simple list for inputting my finances as you can see here:

[image: here]

However, this list would soon become very long and my spreadsheet would be extremely messy because I have some other analyticts stuff in there. So, I would like to make the whole area from the image scrollable, like you can see on the following

[image: picture]

I followed some tutorials, such as [this one](https://www.educba.com/scrollbar-in-excel/), but they're all not what I want to have. So far, I have already inserted the scrollbar, but I have no idea which formula I have to put into the cells, in order to make it work like its supposed to do.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: "...they're all not what I want to have" can you expand on what it is you want, exactly. I also don't see the relationship between formulas and scroll bars you are looking for

Comment: I am not a native speaker, so sorry for my inconcrete statement. I meant that the tutorial, I listed in my question, and many other too all relate to something different. For example, they have a list with 50 entries and create an other list next to this one, which contains the same content, but is srollable. But in my case, I don't have another list, I just want to make the one I have scrollable and don't take the content from another list

Comment: Are you trying to lock your column headings in place so that when you scroll further down your long list of expenses you can still see which column is which? And maybe do the same for the row headings (comment column) so that you can scroll across and not lose your place? Have you looked at using the "Freeze panes" feature?

Comment: Like you can see on the scrollbar next to the picture in the question I would like to scroll only in this area if I want to. I usually use my mousewheel or the scrollbar at the left side of my screen, but this scrolls through the whole document rather than only the one part with my income and expenses. Another [image](https://imgur.com/a/gKJfrXm) for further clarification (the left side shows how it's implemented now and the rigth side shows how I wish it to look like)